# How to get unique values in group_concat?

Tags: mysql

After some searches I found the following that I thought would solve my problem:
http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php

I am running the following in MYSQL

```
SELECT p.object_id, GROUP_CONCAT(p.user_id) as users
FROM objects p 
GROUP BY p.user_id
```

I want to get data that returns looking like this:

```
object_id | users

    64904  2181103, 2186761
    64903  2186757
    64902  2186755, 2186756
    64901  2185796
    64900  2185796
```

Instead, my data is returning with the same value repeating like this:

```
object_id | users

    64904  2181103, 2181103
    64903  2186757
    64902  2186755, 2186755
    64901  2185796
    64900  2185796
```

My table looks like this:

```
object_id | user_id
64904       2181103
64904       2186761
64903       2186757
64902       2186755
64902       2186756
64902       2186755
64902       2186756
64901       2185796
64900       2185796
```

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `GROUP BY p.user_id` should be `GROUP BY p.object_id`.

Comment: smh - it's always right in front of your face.  Thanks a million.  I've lost a few hours on this :(

Comment: We've all been there, man.  I was struggling the other day for hours because I spelled "commercial" wrong >.>

Answer (score 2):

Most, if not all, aggregate functions in MySQL can take advantage of a DISTINCT modifier within the function call, like so:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.user_id) AS users
COUNT(DISTINCT p.user_id) AS userCount
etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

`GROUP_CONCAT()` takes an optional `DISTINCT`. Also, as noted in a comment, your group by looks off.

Try this:

```
  SELECT p.object_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.user_id) as users
    FROM objects p 
    GROUP BY p.object_id
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL needs to know what field to group on, which fields to combine together.

If you want the list of users for each object, then you want to group on `object_id`.

```
SELECT p.object_id, GROUP_CONCAT(p.user_id) as users
FROM objects p 
GROUP BY p.object_id
```